On a curve of genus 1 every indecomposable rank 2 vector bundle of even degree is an extension of the form $ 0 \to M \rightarrow E \to M \to 0 $
This is from Mukai's book on invariants and moduli spaces.

Proposition 10.48. On a curve of genus 1 every indecomposable rank 2 vector bundle of even degree is an extension of the form
$$
0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow E \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0
$$
for some line bundle $M$ on $C$.
Proof. It will be sufficient to consider the case $\operatorname{deg} E=2$. By Riemann-Roch, $h^{0}(E) \geq 2$, so that we can use two linearly independent sections $s, t \in H^{0}(E)$ to construct a homomorphism
$$
f: \mathcal{O}_{C} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{C} \rightarrow E, \quad(a, b) \mapsto a s+b t
$$
Claim: $f$ is injective.
Suppose not. Then the image is a subsheaf of rank 1 , and we denote its saturation by $L \subset E$. Then $\operatorname{deg} L \geq 2$ because $h^{0}(L) \geq 2$. But this contradicts Lemma 10.40. Since $\operatorname{deg} E=2$, the homomorphism $f$ cannot be surjective. In other words, there exists some point $p \in C$ at which the induced map $k \oplus k \rightarrow E / E(-p)$ fails to be an isomorphism. This means that $E$ contains $\mathcal{O}_{C}(p)$ as a subsheaf and, by Lemma 10.40, as a line subbundle. The quotient line bundle $M=E / \mathcal{O}_{C}(p)$ then has degree 1 . But indecomposability of $E$ implies that $H^{1}\left(M^{-1}(p)\right) \neq 0$, and hence $M$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{C}(p)$, proving the proposition.

For reference, Lemma 10.40 states that if $E$ is an indecomposable vector bundle of rank $2$, then every line subbundle $L \subset E$ satisﬁes $2\deg L \le \deg E + 2g -2$.
Mukai loses me after stating that $f$ cannot be surjective. I don't understand how the surjectivity of $f$ is equivalent to there existing a point $p \in C$ at which the induced map $k \oplus k \rightarrow E / E(-p)$ fails to be an isomorphism? I tried to search what on earth the notation $E(-p)$ is supposed to mean, but he does not state this in the book.

$E(-p)=E\otimes\mathcal O_C(-p)$, and $E/E(-p)$ is the fiber of the vector bundle $E$ over the point $p$.

Expanding on my comment, on any curve $C$ we have an exact sequence
$$0\to\mathcal O_C(-p)\to\mathcal O_C\to\mathcal O_p\to 0.$$
Tensoring it with a bundle $E$ we get
\begin{equation}0\to E(-p)\to E\to E_p\to 0,\end{equation}
where $E_p$ is a fiber of $E$ over $p$ (a vector space of dimension $\mathrm{rk}\ E$). In our case, since $f$ is not surjective, it is not surjective on stalks of sheaves over some point. By Nakayama's Lemma, it is not surjective on stalks tensored with the residue field. So we get that $k\oplus k\to E_p$ is not surjective, hence it is not injective, and we get a nonzero global section of $E$, which maps to zero in $E_p$, hence we get a global section of $E(-p)$, or a map $\mathcal O_C(p)\to E$.

Is this specific to curves only or in the higher dimensional case can we replace $-p$ with  a divisor $D$? @danneks

It depends on what you want to get. Firstly, for an effective divisor $D$ there is an exact sequence $0\to\mathcal O(-D)\to\mathcal O\to\mathcal O_D\to 0.$ Secondly, one can consider the ideal sheaf $\mathcal I_p$ of a point $p$. It is not locally free in the higher dimensional case, but gives an exact sequence $0\to\mathcal I_p\to\mathcal O\to\mathcal O_p\to 0.$

Strictly speaking, one should take a Cartier divisor, which is the same as a Weil divisor if we work on a smooth variety.

I see, thank you for the clarification. If you don't mind, can I ask how is $E_p$ identified with the fiber of the underlying bundle? If I was to be completely formal, I think we would have to distinguish between the locally free sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ and the bundle $E$. I know that $E_p \cong \mathcal{E}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p\mathcal{E}_p$, but I don't see how $\mathcal{E}\otimes \mathcal{O}_p$ or $\mathcal{E}/\mathcal{E}(-p)$ give the fibre $E_p$? @danneks

It follows from two facts: that $\mathcal O_p\cong\mathcal O_{X,p}/{\mathfrak m_p \mathcal O_{X,p}}$ and that for any commutative ring $A$ with an ideal $I$ and an $A$-module $M$ we have $M\otimes_A A/I\cong M/IM$.

I see. How do you exactly define $\mathcal{O}p$ if it is only isomorphic to $\mathcal O{X,p}/{\mathfrak m_p \mathcal O_{X,p}}$? @danneks

I mean that $\mathcal O_p$ is a sheaf of modules supported at the point $p$ with these values.
